# KendoPivot and Mondrian XML/A server

Tags: kendo-ui, mondrian

I would like to know if anyone has implemented [KendoPivot](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pivotgrid/index) accessing an instance of [Mondrian](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/mondrian/) as XML/A server. In theory this should work but I'm wondering if there are any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested KendoPivot and Mondrian, and it works well. What you need to take into account is that you have to name your hierarchies, if you don't it'll take the default name (the dimension name). For example you need to include `name="theStore"`:

```
<Dimension name="Store">
  <Hierarchy hasAll="true" primaryKey="store_id" name="theStore">
    <Table name="store"/>
    <Level name="Store Country" column="store_country" uniqueMembers="true"/>
    <Level name="Store State" column="store_state" uniqueMembers="true"/>
    .....
    .....
```